# Why does this Laravel seeder fail?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this simple seeder function; I've already written the Factories and they're fine, and all the Models define the relationships correctly. It should create 5 Users, and then on each User, add one Pic.

```
$this->command->info('Creating sample users...');

$usersCollection = factory(App\Models\User::class, 5)->create();

foreach ($usersCollection as $user) {

    $this->command->info('Adding pictures to user ' . $user->ID . '...');

    $user->pics()->create(
        factory(App\Models\Pic::class, 1)->make()->toArray()
    );

    $this->command->info('Done with user ' . $user->ID . '...');
};
```

However, it just adds one user, then gets stuck trying to add the Pics. It hangs for a long, long time after the 'Adding pictures' message, and eventually produces this error message:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, int given, called in /Users/ericmueller/Sync/Development/dn2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 866`

And when I look in the DB, I see the 5 Users but nothing in the Pics table.

What am I doing wrong?

BONUS QUESTION - I will eventually seed the DB with something like 500 Users, each with up to 5 Pics. Is this the best way to structure the seeder code?

Comment: what happens if you use it like that:  factory(App\Models\Pic::class, 1)->make()->first()->toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead, as i'm a little confused why you are converting an object of type `Pic` to an `Array`.

```
$users = factory(App\Models\User::class, 5)->create();

$users->each(function ($user) {
    $user->pics()->save(
        factory(App\Models\Pic::class)->make()
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't exactly know what your  `$user->pics()` function does,
I have two different options in mind:

Option #1:

```
factory(App\Models\Pic::class, 1)->make()->first()->toArray();
```

You will need to call the `first()` method, because otherwise you get a collection and not a single instance.

Option #2:

```
$pic = factory(App\Models\Pic::class, 1)->make()->first();
$pic->user_id = $user->id;
$pic->save();
```

Create a `Pic` instance and set the `user_id`, afterwards save it.